# Problems calling objective c @dynamic properties from objective c runtime

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm writing lib for accessing objective c from python, so I'm using Cython and objective c runtime for access to objective c. Let we say user declare property on this way:

```
@property (assign) NSString *prop_nsstring_dyn;
```

And he wants to use @dynamic with this property. Okay, let we use this macro:

```
#define ADD_DYNAMIC_PROPERTY(PROPERTY_TYPE, PROPERTY_NAME, SETTER_NAME) \
\
@dynamic prop_nsstring_dyn; \
- ( PROPERTY_TYPE ) PROPERTY_NAME \
{ \
printf("returning\n"); \
return ( PROPERTY_TYPE ) objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(PROPERTY_NAME)); \
} \
\
- (void) SETTER_NAME :( PROPERTY_TYPE ) PROPERTY_NAME \
{ \
printf("setting\n"); \
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(PROPERTY_NAME), PROPERTY_NAME, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN); \
} \
```

After this we can call this in @implementation:

```
ADD_DYNAMIC_PROPERTY(NSString*, prop_nsstring_dyn, setProp_nsstring_dyn);
```

And if we call from objective c on this way:

```
c.prop_nsstring_dyn = @"test str";
```

or

```
c.prop_nsstring_dyn;
```

getters and setters are called correctly.
BUT, I need to set and get value of this dynamic property from objective c runtime, so if I use functions like objc_getIvar/objc_setIvar getters and setters aren't called at all, and I'm getting null pointer as result.

Does anyone knows something about how to call get/set funcs. of dynamic property from objective c runtime?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you investigate pyobjc?

Comment: yes, I looked at pyobjc source, and they have different approach than I, but I think that answer of @Nathan Day will help me

Comment: Cool;  just making sure you weren't reinventing that particular wheel. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the setter and getter methods indirectly by using the NSObject methods

```
- [NSObject setValue:(id) forKey:(NSString *)];
- (id)[NSObject valueForKey:(NSString *)];
```

where the key is the property name, if the property is a primative type like unsigned long, double etc. Then the setValue and value methods will deal with NSNumber equivalents.

Also you can call the property setter and getter the same way you call other methods, so you can use all of the dynamic method invocation features you can use with regular methods, thought you probable have already worked that out.

Comment: Is there any way to get with objc runtime actual IMP of getters and setters for some property?

Comment: Not if you don't implement them somewhere;  the KVC mechanism will fall back to direct access if the methods don't exist.   If they are implemented -- either directly, by synthesis, or generated at runtime -- then they'll behave like any other method.

Answer (score 4):

> getters and setters are called correctly. BUT, I need to set and get value of this dynamic property from objective c runtime, so if I use functions like objc_getIvar/objc_setIvar getters and setters aren't called at all, and I'm getting null pointer as result.

This is your mistake. You should not be calling `objc_getIvar` or `objc_setIvar` to interact with another objects properties. Properties are not ivars. Properties are promises to implement methods. You cannot assume how those methods are implemented. You certainly cannot assume they are equivalent to a call to `objc_getIvar` (as you're discovering).

@NathanDay's approach, using KVC, is a decent approach, but `[obj valueForKey:@"foo"]` is not exactly the same thing as `[obj foo]`. Still, it's close.

First, to be clear, you do not really "get the value of an object's property." You don't even really "call object methods." You send messages to objects and they return results. Properties are mostly a convenient way to declare that you will respond to certain messages (selectors).

To send messages correctly, you'll have to call `objc_msgSend`. Note that there are several forms of it, depending on whether the return value is a floating point or a struct (which is the nice thing about using `valueForKey:`; it makes all return values look the same and you don't need to know which form of `objc_msgSend` to call). In any case you need to know how to interpret the return value, since it might be an `id` or it it might be scalar.

I do not believe it's possible to determine the return type for a selector at runtime in the most general case (for instance, if the class implements `forwardingTargetForSelector:`). You really should get this information from the header file at compile time. But in most cases, you can determine the return values at runtime using `class_getProperty` and `property_getAttributes`, or `class_getInstanceMethod` and `method_getReturnType` (you need to check both; there's no rule that developer must declare "property-like things" with `@property`).

While it's possible to get the actual C function pointer to the implementation of a method, you should generally not do this from outside of an object. There are many ways for ObjC objects to handle messages that do not translate into "call a method with that name". You should pass messages and let the object handle things itself.

But for reading and writing properties, Nathan's KVC approach is possibly all you need. Still, I'd really recommend you take another look at PyObjC, since they've already solved these issues. At the very least, I'd study their code very closely.

Comment: I solved problem on Nathan's KVC approach, and it is working now :)